# How to include assembly info to xsltc-compiled dll?

Tags: asp.net, assembly, xsltc

I need to **include assembly info on my dll** which I manually compiled the XSLT files using command prompt with XSLTC.exe. Anyone knows how? ILmerge?

Answer (score 0):

Details provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399405.aspx).

```
xsltc [options] [/class:<name>] <sourceFile> [[/class:<name>] <sourceFile>...]
```

> /out: assemblyName
>
> Specifies the name of the assembly that is output. The assembly name defaults to the name of the main style sheet or the first style sheet if multiple style sheets are present.
>
> If the style sheet contains scripts, the scripts are saved to a separate assembly. Script assembly names are generated from the main assembly name. For example, if you specified CustOrders.dll for your assembly name, the first script assembly is named CustOrders_Script1.dll.

Comment: Thanks. But this only specify assembly file name, is there a way to have assembly info, e.g: File/product version, Product name, Copyright and etc. embedded onto the file?

Comment: I don't know. The page I linked does state "You cannot generate signed assemblies with xsltc.exe.", but I'm uncertain as to what it really means (this stuff is new to me).